# Marker missing from React Geolocation Google Maps API

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

Hi I'm using the following code in my React app to show current location. But I'm missing the marker that shows exact location. What am I missing? The geolocation pulls up the map that shows the area but not the marker.  How do I add a marker?

```
import React from 'react';
import { GoogleApiWrapper, Map } from "google-maps-react";

export class MapContainer extends React.Component {
  state = { userLocation: { lat: 32, lng: 32 }, loading: true };

  componentDidMount(props) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;

        this.setState({
          userLocation: { lat: latitude, lng: longitude },
          loading: false,

        });
      },
      () => {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, userLocation } = this.state;
    const { google } = this.props;

    if (loading) {
      return null;
    }

    return <Map google={google} initialCenter={userLocation} zoom={15} />;

  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: "API_KEY"
})(MapContainer);
```

Answer (score 0):

To show the a marker in your user position, you need to use the Marker object of the google-maps-react. Here are the steps to do this:

1. Add `Marker` in your import from `google-maps-react`
2. Inside your `<Map/>` object in the `return`, add the `<Marker/>` object with `position={userLocation}`

Here's the code snippet:

```
import React from 'react';
import { GoogleApiWrapper, Map, Marker } from 'google-maps-react';

export class MapContainer extends React.Component {
  state = { 
  userLocation: { lat: 32, lng: 32 }, 
  loading: true };

  componentDidMount(props) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;

        this.setState({
          userLocation: { lat: latitude, lng: longitude },
          loading: false
        });
      },
      () => {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, userLocation } = this.state;
    const { google } = this.props;

    if (loading) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <Map google={google} initialCenter={userLocation} zoom={15}>
        <Marker
          position={userLocation}
        />
      </Map>
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: 'API_KEY'
})(MapContainer);
```